# Validation Rule for Phone Numbers

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

I'm trying to create a validation rule for our phone numbers. Every number has 3 parts:

- Country Code (numerical, min. 1 digit, max 3 digits, starts with '+')
- Area Code (numerical, min. 1 digit, max 4 digits, cannot start with 0)
- Number (numerical, no digit limit, cannot start with 0)

Examples:

+32 12 1234567

+359 123 1234567899

I checked many examples, unfortunately I cannot find out how to say that every parts' digit numbers should be variable (country code could have min. 1 and max. 3 digits) and cannot start with 0

Answer (score 1):

The solution I just came with:

**NOT(REGEX(Phone,"[+]\d\d?\d?\s\d\d?\d?\d?\s\d+"))**

Explaination:

[+]      (the obligatory "+" at the beginning)

**Country Code:**

\d\d?\d?      (min 1 digit, max. 3 digits)

\s         (whitespace)

**Area Code**

\d\d?\d?\d?      (min 1 digit, max. 4 digits)

\s         (whitespace)

**Number**

\d+     (min 1 digit)